# Is this subset of a smooth manifold, a submanifold?

Tags: manifolds

I'm not much informed about manifold but I should answer some questions about it. Based on the definition I have written an answer for the following question but I feel there is something wrong with it! Could you please help me?
Q:
Let M be a smooth manifold and suppose that we have an open cover for that. If S is a subset of M such that the intersection of each element of that cover and S is a submanifold, then S itself is a submanifold.

A:
Fix an arbitrary point p in M. This point belongs to an element of that cover and as we know the intersection of that element with S is a submanifold, so there exists a map around p such that satisfies the condition, so we are done!

Comment: Note that you need to modify the hypothesis: it should say "suppose we have an _open_ cover." Otherwise, the conclusion is clearly false. For example "a cover" could be the collection of all one-point sets in $M$, in which case the hypothesis is satisfied no matter what $S$ is.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. The common way of expressing this idea is by saying "being a manifold is a *local* property".